# WPF Combobox Selected Item Disappearing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am having some trouble with the WPF combobox. My application uses the combobox to list available IP addresses to connect to and will auto fill the last selected IP address on startup. So when the application launches and a file is loaded the box appears as follows:

[image: Combobox with ip address]

When the connect button is clicked my program launches another program that will start and then be minimized by my application. When focus is returned to my application the combobox is now empty as follows:

[image: Empty combobox]

At first my thought was a binding error (nothing is reported in the console) however that does not appear to be the case. Both the property that the selected item is bound to and the selected item itself (on the WPF element) are valid. I have set a breakpoint on the setter for the property and nothing out of the ordinary happens. I also have a separate thread print the selected item every 0.5 seconds directly from the WPF element. Even after the IP address is no longer visible, the selected item is still "192.168.3.106."

Does anyone have any ideas on what could be the problem. The relevant code is below. If any more information is needed, just let me know.

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Name="Stack">
    <Label Content="Active Projector"/>
    <ComboBox
                    Name="ProjectorComboBox"
                    BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Width="140" 
                    ToolTip="Select the projector to use." 
                    Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectorSettings.Projectors}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProjector}">
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding IP}"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
public Projector SelectedProjector
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedProjector;

    }
    set
    {

        if (value == null)
        {
            System.Windows.Input.Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
            return;
        }

        _selectedProjector = value;
        FirePropertyChanged("SelectedProjector");

        _autoSelectedProjector = false;

        RefreshProjector();

    }
}

public void LaserComboboxLoaded()
{
    var currentProjector = Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\SOFTWARE\\LAP\\LaserProjector\\Settings", "GatewayIP", string.Empty);

    if (currentProjector != null)
    {
        foreach (Projector proj in _projectorSettings.Projectors)
        {
            if (proj.IP == currentProjector as string)
            {
                _selectedProjector = proj;
                FirePropertyChanged("SelectedProjector");

                if (!LaserTool.IsProjecting)
                {
                    _autoSelectedProjector = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More likely you are not overriding `Equals()` in `Projector`, therefore comparison by references is used and if selected `Projector` **instance** is not found in the `ProjectorSettings.Projectors` list you will have `ComboBox` displaying blank value.

Comment: @Sinatr I do not compare Projector objects directly, so unless there is an internal comparison that I am not aware of, I do not see that as being the issue.

Comment: Of course there is comparison: `ComboBox` **doesn't change** its current `SelectedItem` if you only change `ItemsSource`. It will try to keep it (by performing lookup in the new collection of items), but since *comparison* fails it displays blank value. I am not claiming that would fix your issue (provide [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want it to be fixed), but missing `Equals()` is probably one of the most common reasons for empty `CombBox`.

Comment: @Sinatr That is just it though, I am not changing `ItemsSource`. I am changing `SelectedProjector`. I did, however, try implementing the Equals method with no results. I will get to work on the mcve and update when complete.